# Perturbative solution of a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I'm in trouble with the following $PDE$
$$\partial_t\rho(x,t)=(1-2\rho(x,t))\partial_x\rho(x,t)$$
I'm finding solutions of the previous equation given the following initial condition:
$$\rho(x,0)=\rho_0+\epsilon\rho_1(x)$$
where $\rho_0$ is a constant and $\rho_1(x)=sin(\omega x)$
Can I use a perturbative approach if $\epsilon$ is small enough? If the answer is 'yes', how much $\epsilon$ has to be small in order to consider the perturbative approach good, even if I understand the word 'good' could be misleading?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this belongs to a PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fpde/fpde2203.pdf.

The solution of this PDE question is $\begin{cases}\rho=\rho_0+\epsilon\sin\omega u\\x=u+(1-2(\rho_0+\epsilon\sin\omega u))t\end{cases}$